# Dynamics 2011 Web Services Don't Work

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Brand new installation of Dynamics 2011 on a brand new Hyper-V virtual machine running Windows 2008 R2. SQL 2008 R2 installed on the VM immediately prior to the Dynamics install. Nothing else is installed on the box. IIS was not installed prior to the Dynamics install.

I try to call the asmx CrmService. I get

```
The request failed with HTTP status 405: Method Not Allowed.
```

I tried setting the app pool to run in 32 bit mode as suggested by some articles I've seen (though those are regarding AX 2009...). After trying that I get a page not found trying to browse to the Dynamics site. If I set it back to 64 bit after that, I still can't browse to the Dynamics site anymore and need to do a repair install.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tested this from IE?  What is the exact URL you are calling?

Comment: Yes...it displays the wsdl fine if I browse to ?wsdl. The url is http://localhost/MSCRMServices/2007/CrmServiceWsdl.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRM 4 web services are deprecated in CRM 2011 but should still work for backwards compatibility.  Someone resolved this problem at the following site - http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/59522e3e-dab4-4038-b790-b9118df4a4a5

Would you be able to post some sample code of what you were trying to excavate?

Comment: I've updated the question with the code. Sorry for the delayed reply.

Comment: I figured it out! Turned out I needed to set my app pool to run in .NET 4.0. Something changed it otherwise... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're hitting the CRM 4 era services. Is that intentional? The 2011 service is at XRMServices/2011/OrganizationService.svc.

Comment: Yes, it's intentional, but they should still be supported, right?